# School district using Windows 8 tablets over BYOD network. How should this be set up?

Tags: windows

I'm sorry for the ambiguity of this post but I was left with quite a mess it seems. I recently came on to this job and there was a deployment of about 120 Windows 8 tablets to 4 different schools. I don't know who created the image or how they were planning to manage the tablets and I am unable to even find out who it was.

It is set up with an admin account which is also a Microsoft account. There is also a local student account on each machine. The admin account is set as a parent account through family and safety center.

The goal of these machines was to have students log in and use some pre-installed educational apps. However, when the student logs in to the local student account, the apps have an (X) on them and if I try to open it, it will bring me to the MS Store and a dialog box appears saying the app needs to be repaired. I click repair, I am prompted to log in with a Microsoft account and I log in with the admin account. This does repair the app and makes all other pre-installed apps work correctly.  This only worked up to a point though. Eventually I got an error message that the Microsoft account can only be linked to 81 PCs.

I have tried creating a new Microsoft account that is also set as a parent account, but when I use that account to login on the repair screen, nothing happens.

I sadly have no idea how I should have these tablets set up. I have tried creating a new account which has been designated as an adult account in family and safety but that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is going to be far outside the scope of the site because you're asking for a hugely broad answer.

Right now, I will say that it sounds like someone's tried to bodge using home tools (shared accounts, parental controls) for an enterprise deployment situation and that never ends well.

I suggest you look at a Mobile Device Management ([MDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management)) solution. For Windows in an educational environment, I suggest starting with Microsoft's [Windows Intune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/microsoft-intune/), even though I'm not big fan myself.

This will allow you to manage the tablet "environment" and deploy apps in a much more controlled and robust way than fiddling around with parental/admin accounts locally on each tablet, not to mention doing a far better job of locking the systems down so that they are secure and safeguarding obligations can more easily be met.

A good MDM deployment will even allow you to do things like wipe devices remotely if they're stolen, deploy *and* remove apps, re-image devices on demand, etc.

Comment: This is true. The whole system needs  a re-design to cater for more of an enterprise approach as managing this system would be incredibly difficult using the standard built-in tools

Comment: There are relatively easy ways to handle this but I'd reach out to your Microsoft rep to see what you have available as part of the subscription.  Are you also using OneNote classrooms?